# Generic strongly-typed scala method to retrieve item of a particular type from a collection

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

Imagine I have this class:

```
class Example {
    val list = List(new Apple(), new Orange(), Banana());
    def getIfPresent[T <: Fruit] : Option[T] = list.collectFirst { case x : T => x }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
val example = new Example();
match example.getIfPresent[Apple] {
    case Some(apple) => apple.someAppleSpecificMethod();
    case None => println("No apple");
}
```

Now, of course, this doesn't work in the JVM, because of type erasure. `getIfPresent` just matches on the type `Fruit` in the `collectFirst` partial function, instead of the actual type specified in the call.

I have tried to get my head around type tags and class tags, and really have no idea how I would implement the above method. The examples that I see are trying to do very different things. How could I achieve a method that does what I want, either with TypeTags or some other mechanism I'm unaware of?

---

Edit: m-z's answer below is the full solution, but here is how it looks with my example code:

```
class Example {
    val list = List(new Apple(), new Orange(), Banana());
    def getIfPresent[T <: Fruit : ClassTag] : Option[T] = list.collectFirst { case x : T => x }
}
```

Just needed to add `: ClassTag`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using `ClassTag`, to an extent.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

// Modify to apply whatever type bounds you find necessary
// Requires Scala ~2.11.5 or greater (not sure of the exact version, but 2.11.1 does not work, and 2.11.5 does)
def findFirst[A : ClassTag](list: List[Any]): Option[A] =
    list collectFirst { case a: A => a }

val l = List(1, "a", false, List(1, 2, 3), List("a", "b"))

scala> findFirst[Boolean](l)
res22: Option[Boolean] = Some(false)

scala> findFirst[Long](l)
res23: Option[Long] = None
```

But there are some caveats with `ClassTag`, in that it will only match the class, and not the type:

```
scala> findFirst[List[String]](l)
res24: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3)) // No!
```

You can use a `TypeTag` to get around this, but it won't work with a `List[Any]`. Here is one possible (sort of ugly) trick:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{typeOf, TypeTag}

case class Tagged[A : TypeTag](a: A) {
    def tpe = typeOf[A]
}

implicit class AnyTagged[A : TypeTag](a: A) {
    def tag = Tagged(a)
}

def findFirst[A : TypeTag](list: List[Tagged[_]]): Option[A] =
    list collectFirst { case tag @ Tagged(a) if(tag.tpe =:= typeOf[A]) => a.asInstanceOf[A] }
```

The only way I can think of to hold onto the `TypeTag` of each element is to literally hold onto it with a wrapper class. So I have to construct the list like this:

```
val l = List(1.tag, "a".tag, false.tag, List(1, 2, 3).tag, List("a", "b").tag)
```

But it works:

```
scala> findFirst[List[String]](l)
res26: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(a, b))
```

There may be a more elegant way to construct such a list with `TypeTag`s.

---

For fun, you can also try to do this with [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) using an `HList` and `select`. The difference is that instead of returning `Option[A]`, `select` will return `A` (the type you want), but if the `HList` contains no `A`, *it won't compile*.

```
import shapeless._

val l = 1 :: "a" :: false :: List(1, 2, 3) :: List("a", "b") :: HNil

scala> l.select[Boolean]
res0: Boolean = false

scala> l.select[Boolean]
res1: Boolean = false

scala> l.select[List[String]]
res2: List[String] = List(a, b)

scala> l.select[Long]
<console>:12: error: Implicit not found: shapeless.Ops.Selector[shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[Boolean,shapeless.::[List[Int],shapeless.::[List[String],shapeless.HNil]]]]], Long]. You requested an element of type Long, but there is none in the HList shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[Boolean,shapeless.::[List[Int],shapeless.::[List[String],shapeless.HNil]]]]].
              l.select[Long]
                      ^
```